# Open FindInFiles dialog from Visual Studio Extension

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

I am writing a Visual Studio extension, and I would like to open the FindInFiles dialog **with “Current Document” set as scope**.

In MS documentation, I ended up finding fields that sound promising:

- VSConstants.StandardToolWindows.FindInFiles;
- VSConstants.VSStd97CmdID.FindInFiles;
- ToolWindowGuids80.FindInFiles…

But I couldn't find a way to actually use them to open the dialog.

I tried a few variations of this code (by changing the various constants):

```cs
var mcs = ServiceProvider.GetServiceAsync(typeof(IMenuCommandService)).Result as MenuCommandService;
var command = new CommandID(
    VSConstants.StandardToolWindows.FindInFiles,
    (int)VSConstants.VSStd97CmdID.FindInFiles);
mcs.GlobalInvoke(command, VSConstants.StandardToolWindows.FindInFiles);
```

But I did not manage to get the dialog to pop. Plus it sounded a lot like fiddling.

So how can I get my addin to open the SearchInFiles dialog? And more importantly, where did you find the answer ?

Comment: try to use [dte.ExecuteCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte._dte.executecommand?view=visualstudiosdk-2017)(
"Edit.FindInFiles","/ lookin:Current Document"). More Find in Files Commands, you can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/find-in-files-command?view=vs-2019).

Answer (score 0):

You can call the **Edit.FindInFiles** command to open the dialog:

```
dte.ExecuteCommand("Edit.FindInFiles");
```

Comment: I stopped trying this approach because it did not seem to allow me to set the scope (to Current Document) without starting the search.